# Java - Editar Registro do Windows

Tags: java

Como eu posso alterar um registro (regedit) do Windows?
E se a chave não existe como posso fazer para criar?

Comment: Que tal [essas respostas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/62289/read-write-to-windows-registry-using-java)?

Answer (score 2):

Um programa em java não deveria precisar escrever no registro do windows, já que o principal motivo de usar java deveria ser a independência de plataforma, na minha opinião. Entretanto, a teoria é a teoria e a prática é a pratica. Portanto, não vou aqui tentar dissuadi-lo de utilizar registro do windows em uma aplicação java, pois isso não responderia a pergunta e levaria a uma discussão talvez muito grande nos comentários.

A maneira mais comum que a comunidade utiliza para interagir com código nativo para o Sistema Operacional windows, é a [bibioteca JNA](https://jna.java.net/javadoc/platform/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/class-use/WinReg.HKEY.html).

Especificamente, após adicionar a jar ao seu projeto, você deverá utilizar o pacote `com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Advapi32Util`:

`import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Advapi32Util`

Para verificar se uma chave existe, o método é o seguinte:

```
Advapi32Util.registryKeyExists(WinReg.HKEY root, java.lang.String key);
```

Assinatura:

```
public static boolean registryKeyExists(WinReg.HKEY root,
                                        java.lang.String key)
```

1. O Primeiro parâmetro recebe os possíveis valores:

   - `WinReg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER`
   - `WinReg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`
   - etc
2. O segundo parâmetro é o nome da chave.

Para ler um valor, utilize:

Para string:

```
public static java.lang.String registryGetStringValue(WinReg.HKEY root,
                                                          java.lang.String key,
                                                          java.lang.String value)
```

Para Inteiro:

```
public static int registryGetIntValue(WinReg.HKEY root,
                                          java.lang.String key,
                                          java.lang.String value)
```

E assim sucessivamente, veja alguns exemplos (inglês, mas código é código): [Exemplo 1](http://code.dblock.org/2010/03/23/jna-accessing-windows-registry-from-java.html), [Exemplo 2](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-read-write-windows-registry-using-jna.html)